# What is __memset_sse2 and why does it perform so many instructions?

Tags: c++, performance

I have two C++ implementations of an algorithm, call them `A` and `B`. The only difference between `A` and `B` is that `A` uses `std::unordered_map<int, int> hashmap;` but `B` uses `google::dense_hash_map<int, int> hashmap;`.

I found an input where `A` is so much slower compared to `B` and I can not understand why.

For the same input, I run `sudo perf record -e instructions ./A input.txt`

and then I get this result:

```
Overhead  Command  Shared Object        Symbol
  65.90%  A        libc-2.23.so         [.] __memset_sse2
   6.63%  A        libc-2.23.so         [.] _int_malloc
   3.44%  A        libc-2.23.so         [.] malloc
   2.61%  A        libc-2.23.so         [.] _int_free
```

When I do the same for `B` which is faster, I get the following:

```
Overhead  Command  Shared Object        Symbol
  15.17%  B        libc-2.23.so         [.] _int_malloc
  14.94%  B        B                    [.] B::func1()
   5.72%  B        B                    [.] B::func2()
   5.58%  B        B                    [.] B::func3()
```

What is `__memset_sse2` and why does it perform so many instructions?

Comment: `__memset_sse2` is just SSE2-optimized version of [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset). Try to run `perf` with `-g` and check call graphs in the output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__memset_sse2` is used in [implementations](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/glibc/+/upstream/release/2.16/master/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memset.S) of `memset` function optimized for architectures that support [SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2). When you see it taking roughly two-thirds of execution time, it means that most of the time goes into initializing a single chunk of memory, which has a relatively large size. A hash table is likely to use `memset` to initialize its hash buckets.

It appears that `google::dense_hash_map` is optimized for size, so it does not need to initialize as much memory when running your example.

**Note:** The observation that initialization takes two thirds of CPU time may mean that your benchmark is not designed correctly. Perhaps the amount of data that you put through your hash container is relatively small, or you keep rebuilding your container in each run.